# Java - PdfReader is blocking my program when reading a specific PDF

Tags: java, pdf

I'm using PdfReader to get the number of pages of a .pdf file. I tested my application on 13 pdfs today, and the 12 firsts were working fine, and the last one is blocking my application. I don't understand why, I can open the file with a FileInputStream and it works, and I can open it with Adobe so I don't think the file have an issue.

Here is how I create my PdfReader :

```
// This line is block my application for the 13th file :
PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader(filename);
int pageCount = pdf.getNumberOfPages();
```

Edit :
Some of theses pdf files are files I zipped in a Zip file, and I unZipped them. The file who is causing troubles is one of them, but others zipped/unZipped files are working fine

Comment: Do you close the underlying streams? I assume you have to close your previous pdf readers. There is not enough details to answer.

Comment: Well, I was thinking about that and no I wasn’t closing my pdf var. Maybe it’s what cause the issue but I’m not sure because other files are working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by adding a dependency in my `pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
   <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
   <version>5.5.9</version>
<dependency>
```

I was using **Maven's** itextpdf library which was in `2.1.7`